# how to upload a csv file from any direcory to database

Tags: php, html

I am adding data from a file to my database. Currently the location of the files are limited to only those inside directory `D:/`. I want to be able to support adding files from multiple directories.

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "root";
$dbname = "stdprt";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}
$filename = "d:/" . $_POST['fname'];
$handle = fopen($filename, "r");
while (($data = fgetcsv($handle)) !== FALSE) {
    $num = count($data);
    $row;
    $sql = "INSERT into marks(regno,semister,subcode,subname,internals,externals,credits)values('$data[0]','$data[1]','$data[2]','$data[3]','$data[4]','$data[5]','$data[6]')";
    //echo "INSERT into marks(regno,semister,subcode,subname,internals,externals,credits)values('$data[0]','$data[1]','$data[2]','$data[3]','$data[4]','$data[5]','$data[6]')";
    if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
        // echo "New record created successfully";
    } else {
        echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
    }
    echo "<br>";
}
?>
<h2>Uploaded Successfully....</h2>
<a href="admin.php">back</a>
```

Comment: not to be pedantic, but, your not uploading a file, your just reading one on the local server. and by the looks of the code load data infile would be a much better idea https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/load-data.html

Comment: $filename="d:/".$_POST['fname'];    it only accepts data from d drive .so i need not d drive,i want to upload from any drive.

Comment: @Naveen As nogad has pointed out, you're not uploading anything. The fact that the client and server is the same machine is causing you confusion. You need to be able to upload data from the client (browser) to the server (PHP/Apache)

Comment: @lee taylor yes u r correct

Comment: @Naveen Your SQL looks open to injection attacks, also. So, Google "html upload files" and "SQL Injection PHP"

Comment: @Lee Taylor i need code for that can u help me.

Comment: @Naveen - There's plenty of code out there. This site is to help people, not to do their work for them. You also need to understand both that and the dangerous code you have (SQL injection)

Comment: im still not sure if you want form file upload, or reading a file from the server?

Comment: i want to upload a .csv file into database.present it only supporting from d drive.i want to upload a .csv file from anywhere to the server.

Comment: again its NOT an upload, the file has to be accessible as what ever php is running as on your server. as its windows - i have no idea how the permissions work.

Answer (score 0):

If you are wanting to choose a file in another drive you can modify this line in your code and change the directory at the start.

`$filename="d:/".$_POST['fname'];`

So for example if you wanted to change the directory to drive F it would be like so:

`$filename="f:/".$_POST['fname'];`

If you wanted to enable the ability to specify a custom directory in your request then you could pass it through the same way you are passing `fname`. Say for example you passed your custom directory along in a key named `cust_dir` you could add it as the directory like so.

```
if($_POST['cust_dir']{
    $filename=$_POST['cust_dir'].$_POST['fname'];
} else {
    $filename="d:/".$_POST['fname'];
}
```

The code above would use a custom directory path that you passed in the $_POST variable if you passed one. If you do not pass `cust_dir` then it will default to directory `d:/`.